# datepicker jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using the following code. For this code datepicker is not shown. But when I click the datepicker div using InspectElement, the datepicker will appear. What is the reason?..

```
<input type="text" id="datePicker" placeholder="Select Date"style="height: 34px;width: 171px;position: relative;left:-21px;border-radius: 5px;"onclick="showDatePicker()">
```

The above one is my text field.

And the js code is

```
function showDatePicker()
{
    $("#datePicker").datepicker();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this, `onclick="showDatePicker()`.

We initialize it like below:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#datePicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

```css
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datePicker" placeholder="Select Date"style="height: 34px;width: 171px;position: relative; border-radius: 5px;">
```

As you notice from the above snippet you need also to reference the jquery-ui as long as the jquery-ui.css. Furthermore, you have to style the datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Onclick action, datepicker is handling this :

```
<input type="text" id="datePicker" placeholder="Select Date" style="height: 34px;width: 171px;position: relative;left:-21px;border-radius: 5px;">
<script>$(function() { $("#datePicker").datepicker(); });</script>
```

Comment: $(function() { ... }) is exactly the same as $(document).ready(function() {})